# How to convert character to factor and reorder factor levels based on the mean of another variable in with ggplot and boxplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, mean, boxplot

I am not sure where I am going wrong.
I have encountered several errors and am attempting to troubleshoot but I'm not understanding the issue. I would appreciate it if you could help me out. My goal is to have a boxplot that has girth on y axis, ForestDiv on x axis, and the ForestDiv needs to be converted to a factor (I think I did this already, but may have screwed it up), and then ForestDiv needs to be reordered by the mean of LatDec.
[image: RStudioScreenshot]
[RstudioScreenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLHzN.jpg).
I have already constructed a boxplot previously, and the only updates needed are what I stated above.

Error in `f()`:
! Aesthetics must be valid data columns. Problematic aesthetic(s): y = FactorForestDiv ~ ....
Did you mistype the name of a data column or forget to add after_stat()?
Backtrace:

1. base (local) `<fn>`(x)
2. ggplot2:::print.ggplot(x)
3. ggplot2:::ggplot_build.ggplot(x)
4. ggplot2 (local) by_layer(function(l, d) l$compute_aesthetics(d, plot))
5. ggplot2 (local) f(l = layers[[i]], d = data[[i]])
6. l$compute_aesthetics(d, plot)
7. ggplot2 (local) f(..., self = self)

```
Join_Macro_Site %>%
 ggplot(mapping = aes(FactorForestDiv ~ fct_reorder(girth, data = FactorForestDiv, ylim(0,200), .fun = mean(LatDec)))) + 
 geom_boxplot() +
 ylim(0,200)

Error in `f()`:
! Aesthetics must be valid data columns. Problematic aesthetic(s): x = FactorForestDiv ~ .... 
Did you mistype the name of a data column or forget to add after_stat()?
Backtrace:
 1. base (local) `<fn>`(x)
 2. ggplot2:::print.ggplot(x)
 4. ggplot2:::ggplot_build.ggplot(x)
 5. ggplot2 (local) by_layer(function(l, d) l$compute_aesthetics(d, plot))
 6. ggplot2 (local) f(l = layers[[i]], d = data[[i]])
 7. l$compute_aesthetics(d, plot)
 8. ggplot2 (local) f(..., self = self)

Join_Macro_Site %>%
 ggplot(mapping = aes() + 
 geom_boxplot() +
 FactorForDiv <- factor(FactorForDiv, levels = data(order(mean(LatDec)), "ForestDiv", levels(ForestDiv)
 ylim(0,200)

Error: unexpected symbol in:
"FactorForDiv <- factor(FactorForDiv, levels = data(order(mean(LatDec)), "ForestDiv", levels(ForestDiv)
ylim"

Join_Macro_Site %>%
 ggplot(mapping = aes() + 
 geom_boxplot() +
 Join_Macro_Site$ForestDiv <- factor(Join_Macro_Site$ForestDiv, levels = Join_Macro_Site[order(Join_Macro_Site$LatDec), "ForestDiv"])
 levels(Join_Macro_Site$ForestDiv)

Error: unexpected symbol in:
"Join_Macro_Site$ForestDiv <- factor(Join_Macro_Site$ForestDiv, levels = Join_Macro_Site[order(Join_Macro_Site$LatDec), "ForestDiv"])
levels"

Join_Macro_Site %>%
 ggplot(mapping = aes() + 
 geom_boxplot() +
 Join_Macro_Site$ForestDiv <- factor(Join_Macro_Site$ForestDiv, levels = Join_Macro_Site[order(Join_Macro_Site$LatDec), "ForestDiv"])
 levels(Join_Macro_Site$ForestDiv) %>%

Error: unexpected symbol in:
"Join_Macro_Site$ForestDiv <- factor(Join_Macro_Site$ForestDiv, levels = Join_Macro_Site[order(Join_Macro_Site$LatDec), "ForestDiv"])
levels"

Join_Macro_Site %>%
 ggplot(mapping = aes() + 
 geom_boxplot() +
 Join_Macro_Site$ForestDiv <- factor(Join_Macro_Site$ForestDiv, levels = Join_Macro_Site[order(Join_Macro_Site$LatDec), "ForestDiv"]), levels(Join_Macro_Site$ForestDiv) %>%
 ylim(0,200)

Error: Incomplete expression: Join_Macro_Site %>%
ggplot(mapping = aes() + 
geom_boxplot() +
Join_Macro_Site$ForestDiv <- factor(Join_Macro_Site$ForestDiv, levels = Join_Macro_Site[order(Join_Macro_Site$LatDec), "ForestDiv"]), levels(Join_Macro_Site$ForestDiv) %>%
ylim(0,200)
```

Comment: First start with: `Join_Macro_Site %>% ggplot(mapping = aes(y= girth, x=ForestDiv)) +  geom_boxplot()`, and see if that gets something to work with.  Also post your data using the output of the `dput()` function, the screen shot of the data is almost useless.

Comment: I already had what you typed input for the previous question, and that is as far as I got before I had a bunch of errors. I am not familiar with the dput() option but I will try to use it. I'm mostly unsure how to go from ```Join_Macro_Site %>% ggplot(mapping = aes(y= girth, x=ForestDiv)) +  geom_boxplot()```  and then convert ForestDiv to a factor, and then reorder by the mean of LatDec. I believe I may have messed up when converting ForestDiv to a factor.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example